# Work Manager unable to work on background thread whille inserting values to database

Tags: android, multithreading, android-workmanager

I have tried fetching data via retrofit and then using the response body i am trying to insert columns to Room Database using Work Manager .
But still it gives error Network on Main thread exception , even if doWork() Method works on Background thread.Please help me with a solution other thaan introducing async task, because if async task is introduced then my WorkManagers default methods such as beginWith(),then() will start working parallely instead of working sequentially.

BillTaxInfoDAO billTaxInfoDAO=db.billTaxInfoDao();
billTaxInfoDAO.insert(billTaxInfo);
these two lines are giving network on main thread exception.

**Error: 
Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:209)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:256)
        at com.witbybit.offlinepos.datamodels.pointofsale.BillTaxInfoDAO_Impl.insert(BillTaxInfoDAO_Impl.java:103)
        at com.witbybit.offlinepos.restore.RestoreManager$4.onResponse(RestoreManager.java:196)**

MyWorker Class

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    try {
        Data data = getInputData();
        String choice = data.getString("method");
        switch (choice) {
            case "back_up_found":{isBackUpfound();break;}
            case "bill_tax_info": {billTaxInfoRestore();break;}
            case "category": {categoryRestore();break;}
            case "customer": {customerRestore();break;}
            case "outlet": {outletRestore();break;}
            case "payment_entry": {paymentEntryRestore();break;}
            case "pos_bill": {posBillRestore();break;}
            case "pos_bill_item": {posBillItemRestore();break;}
            case "pos_item": {posItemRestore();break;}
            case "tax": {taxRestore();break;}
            case "tax_group": {taxGroupRestore();break;}
            case "user": {userRestore();break;}
            case "user_sms_data": {userSMSData();break;}
            default: {Log.wtf(TAG, "default called");}
        }
        return Result.success(data);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.wtf(TAG,"Failed for "+e.getMessage() );
        return Result.failure();
    }

}

public void isBackUpfound(){
    RestoreApiClient restoreApiClient=getRetrofit().create(RestoreApiClient.class);
    Call<List<Object>> call=restoreApiClient.isBackUpFound();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Object>> call, Response<List<Object>> response) {
            for(Object object:response.body()){
                HashMap<String,Double> map=new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(object),HashMap.class);
                double row_count=map.get("row");
                if(row_count>1){
                    Log.wtf("Restore Manager" ,"Backup Found");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Object>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}


private void billTaxInfoRestore(){
    RestoreApiClient apiClient=RestoreManager.getRetrofit().create(RestoreApiClient.class);
    Call<List<Object>> call=apiClient.getEachTableData("bill_tax_info");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Object>> call, Response<List<Object>> response) {
            for (Object object: response.body()) {
                Gson gson=new Gson();
                BillTaxInfo billTaxInfo=gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(object),BillTaxInfo.class);
                //BillsRepository.billTaxInfoInsert(billTaxInfo,getApplicationContext());
                AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
                BillTaxInfoDAO billTaxInfoDAO=db.billTaxInfoDao();
                billTaxInfoDAO.insert(billTaxInfo);
              }
            Log.wtf(TAG,"bills restore complete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Object>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.wtf("Restore Manager","failure "+t);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my Calling fragment class

```
var tax_bill_info_request=OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(RestoreManager::class.java!!)
            .setInputData(Data.Builder().putString("method", "bill_tax_info").build())
            .build()
    var category_request=OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(RestoreManager::class.java!!)
            .setInputData(Data.Builder().putString("method", "category").build())
            .build()
    requests.add(tax_bill_info_request)
    requests.add(category_request)

    WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(tax_bill_info_request.id).observe(this, Observer {
        restore_textview.text =restore_textview.text.toString() + it.outputData.getString("method")+" "+it.state.name
    })

    WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(category_request.id).observe(this, Observer {
        restore_textview.text =restore_textview.text.toString() + it.outputData.getString("method")+" "+it.state.name
    })



    restoreButton?.setOnClickListener{view ->
        try {
            startRestore()
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.wtf(TAG,e.message)
        }
    }


fun startRestore(){
    WorkManager.getInstance()
            .beginWith(requests.get(0))
            .then(requests.get(1))
            .enqueue()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace does not indicate anything with WorkManager.  It looks like your RestoreManager#onResponse is happening on the main thread.  You should check with what's going on with that piece of code.  Perhaps your network responses are automatically delivered to the main thread.